# any virtual machine is planting 16.04 since yesterday!

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

For a strange and unknown reason, since yesterday my Virtual Box VMWare 12 running well Win10 (trying for few weeks) has started to totally get my PC planted!
I tried to install VirtualBox, just to see if it works and exactly the same problem. As soon I am launching Win10 then the PC is frozen.

What could it be?

Thanks
Serros

Comment: Are you allocating your VM too much RAM so that there isn't enough for the host system any more?

Comment: Actually my VM under VMWare was running perfectly for a few weeks with 4GB on 8GB RAM, no problem. But suddenly since yesterday, starting planting. When I just tried VirtualBox, I set only 2GB, but planted as soon I started to boot on ISO file from DVD.

Comment: I just tried again but same problem with VirtualBox! Maybe SSD corrupted?